# Browsers are lagging on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: swap, browser

When I move the page up and down on Twitter I had 3-4 seconds lag on Chrome. Now I'm using Brave. It has the same problem but it is little bit better. What do you think the problem would be? I suspect it would be a swap file problem. I've installed gparted but I don't see a swap partition there.

My laptop has a i3 5th gen CPU, 8 GB Ram and 120gb SSD.
I'm an Ubuntu newby. I can only use the GUI and some basic terminal commands.

```
name of display: :0
```

display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample,
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
GLX_EXT_get_drawable_type, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context,
GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
GLX_ATI_pixel_format_float, GLX_EXT_buffer_age,
GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile,
GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control,
GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event,
GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,
GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context,
GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float,
GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample,
GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float,
GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, GLX_EXT_swap_control,
GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer,
GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method,
GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig,
GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,
GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
Vendor: Intel (0x8086)
Device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) (0x1616)
Version: 23.2.1
Accelerated: yes
Video memory: 7846MB
Unified memory: yes
Preferred profile: core (0x1)
Max core profile version: 4.6
Max compat profile version: 4.6
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth,
GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64,
GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_performance_monitor,
GL_AMD_pinned_memory, GL_AMD_query_buffer_object,
GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax,
GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer,
GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility,
GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance,
GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,
GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control,
GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader,
GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted,
GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image,
GL_ARB_cull_distance, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float,
GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access,
GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend,
GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect,
GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts,
GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport,
GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments,
GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gl_spirv,
GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64,
GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex,
GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays,
GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_internalformat_query2,
GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment,
GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect,
GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile,
GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp,
GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,
GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops,
GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_ballot,
GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_clock,
GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, GL_ARB_shader_group_vote,
GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size,
GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision,
GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine,
GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod,
GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack,
GL_ARB_shading_language_include, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing,
GL_ARB_spirv_extensions, GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync,
GL_ARB_tessellation_shader, GL_ARB_texture_barrier,
GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32,
GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc,
GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array,
GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_ARB_texture_float,
GL_ARB_texture_gather, GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge,
GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two,
GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod,
GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui,
GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, GL_ARB_texture_storage,
GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle,
GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object,
GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object,
GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding,
GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev,
GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate,
GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync,
GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_debug_label,
GL_EXT_demote_to_helper_invocation, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2,
GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_memory_object,
GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float,
GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp,
GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd,
GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, GL_EXT_texture_array,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic,
GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8,
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod,
GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm,
GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback,
GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit,
GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render,
GL_INTEL_performance_query, GL_INTEL_shader_integer_functions2,
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control,
GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile,
GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness,
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y,
GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions,
GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_alpha_to_coverage_dither_control,
GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives, GL_NV_conditional_render,
GL_NV_copy_image, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
GL_NV_texture_barrier, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth,
GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect,
GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_AMD_pinned_memory,
GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,
GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_texture_texture4,
GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index,
GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5,
GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility,
GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility,
GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance,
GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage,
GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control,
GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility,
GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader,
GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted,
GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image,
GL_ARB_cull_distance, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float,
GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_derivative_control,
GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers,
GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex,
GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts,
GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location,
GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport,
GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow,
GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments,
GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB,
GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gl_spirv,
GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64,
GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex,
GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays,
GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_internalformat_query2,
GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment,
GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect,
GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query,
GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile,
GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object,
GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp,
GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex,
GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects,
GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture,
GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops,
GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_ballot,
GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_clock,
GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, GL_ARB_shader_group_vote,
GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size,
GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision,
GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine,
GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod,
GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array, GL_ARB_shading_language_100,
GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_include,
GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_spirv_extensions,
GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader,
GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp,
GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32,
GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc,
GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array,
GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine,
GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3,
GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_ARB_texture_float,
GL_ARB_texture_gather, GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge,
GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_multisample,
GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels,
GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg,
GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_stencil8,
GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample,
GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced,
GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix,
GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra,
GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit,
GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader,
GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev,
GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate,
GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_separate_stencil,
GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3,
GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync,
GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color,
GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate,
GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array,
GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_debug_label,
GL_EXT_demote_to_helper_invocation, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements,
GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object,
GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters,
GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd,
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil,
GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object,
GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp,
GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color,
GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs,
GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture,
GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array,
GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map,
GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add,
GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3,
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer,
GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle,
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode,
GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent,
GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query,
GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra,
GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays,
GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat,
GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render,
GL_INTEL_performance_query, GL_INTEL_shader_integer_functions2,
GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control,
GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile,
GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness,
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y,
GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions,
GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos,
GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility, GL_NV_alpha_to_coverage_dither_control,
GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives,
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image,
GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_half_float,
GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil,
GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier,
GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image,
GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap,
GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp,
GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a,
GL_ANGLE_pack_reverse_row_order, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3,
GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_texture_max_level,
GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_base_instance,
GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_buffer_storage,
GL_EXT_clear_texture, GL_EXT_clip_control, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance,
GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float,
GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture, GL_EXT_copy_image,
GL_EXT_debug_label, GL_EXT_demote_to_helper_invocation,
GL_EXT_depth_clamp, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer,
GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query, GL_EXT_draw_buffers,
GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex,
GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_float_blend, GL_EXT_frag_depth,
GL_EXT_geometry_point_size, GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5,
GL_EXT_instanced_arrays, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, GL_EXT_memory_object,
GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays,
GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp,
GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra,
GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control,
GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects,
GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent, GL_EXT_shader_group_vote,
GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks, GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical,
GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size, GL_EXT_tessellation_shader,
GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_buffer,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc_srgb, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array,
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888,
GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_EXT_texture_norm16,
GL_EXT_texture_query_lod, GL_EXT_texture_rg, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8,
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod,
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_EXT_texture_view,
GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, GL_INTEL_blackhole_render,
GL_INTEL_performance_query, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced,
GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error,
GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior,
GL_KHR_robustness, GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr,
GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_bgra,
GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions,
GL_NV_alpha_to_coverage_dither_control, GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives,
GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments,
GL_NV_generate_mipmap_sRGB, GL_NV_image_formats, GL_NV_pack_subimage,
GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object, GL_NV_read_buffer, GL_NV_read_depth,
GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil,
GL_NV_shader_noperspective_interpolation, GL_OES_EGL_image,
GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3,
GL_OES_EGL_sync, GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture, GL_OES_copy_image,
GL_OES_depth24, GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map,
GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex,
GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
GL_OES_geometry_point_size, GL_OES_geometry_shader,
GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_gpu_shader5, GL_OES_mapbuffer,
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box,
GL_OES_required_internalformat, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading,
GL_OES_sample_variables, GL_OES_shader_image_atomic,
GL_OES_shader_io_blocks, GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation,
GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil8, GL_OES_surfaceless_context,
GL_OES_tessellation_point_size, GL_OES_tessellation_shader,
GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_border_clamp, GL_OES_texture_buffer,
GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array, GL_OES_texture_float,
GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float,
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot,
GL_OES_texture_stencil8, GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array,
GL_OES_texture_view, GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float,
GL_OES_viewport_array

### 272 GLX Visuals
visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat

0x031 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x032 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2ae 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2af 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2b5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  s  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2ba 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2bb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  s  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x2bc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0

Comment: Do you have the (i)GPU drivers installed properly? Please [edit] with `glxinfo`

Comment: I'm running 16GB of ram and rarely use swap, even with it set at 60. Also, swapping shouldn't really slow things down if you're using an SSD, that is unless you don't have any swap to use (or if you have swappiness set too low because then the system will get bogged down when ram is full). To check your swappiness, run `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` On newer versions of Ubuntu, we usually use a swap file instead of a swap partition. To check the size of your swap file, please run `swapon -s`. Otherwise, it could be a DNS issue or something network related too.

Comment: Swappiness is 60. Swap file is like below: 
Filename    Type  Size  Used Priority
/swapfile                               file  8388604  0 -2